# C# парсер не возвращает html

Tags: c#, .net, парсер

Пишу парсер, и пока что просто для теста нужно вывести кол-во страниц с пользователями. Есть 2 функции (код будет ниже). Одна - парсит номер последней страницы с пользователями, вторая - выводит в окнонное приложение месседжбоксом. При компиляции программа сначала попадает в catch, и выдает "**Индекс находится вне границ массива**", далее приложение возвращает 0 (просто изначальное значение переменной, которое почему то не изменилось). С подключенной библиотекой xNet по идее проблем нет . На всякий случай подключил просто все возможные либы xNet:

```
using xNet; 
using xNet.Collections; 
using xNet.IO; 
using xNet.Security; 
using xNet.Threading; 
using xNet.Xml; 
using xNet.Net; 
using xNet.Text;
```

Результат тот же. Сабстрингом, как мне кажется, я вроде бы правильно вычленяю данные (исходный код страницы из браузера тоже прикладываю)

```
<a href="/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=2" class="">2</a>
    <a href="/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=3" class="">3</a>
    <a href="/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=4" class="">4</a>
    <a href="/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=5" class="">5</a>
    <span class="forum-page-dots">...</span>
    <a href="/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=1654">1654</a> //Нужная строка
```

Первая функция, которая парсит:

```
private int GetPages()
{
    int countPages = 0;


    try
    {
        using(var Request = new HttpRequest())
        {

            string sourcePage;

            sourcePage = Request.Get("http://vegeterian.ru/forum/users/").ToString();
            countPages = Convert.ToInt32(sourcePage.Substring("/forum/users/?PAGEN_1=", "\">", 0)[4]);


            MessageBox.Show(sourcePage);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return countPages;

}
```

Вторая функция:

```
private void UI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string pcount = GetPages().ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(pcount);

}
```

Вдобавок к написанному выше, я решил проверить, получаю ли я html и что мне вообще приходит в `sourcePage`, когда я делаю:

```
sourcePage = Request.Get("http://vegeterian.ru/forum/users/").ToString();
```

Компилирую, и в оконное приложение мне возвращается: **xNet.Net.HttpResponse**

Comment: Почитайте `Request` на сайте microsoft -  **msdn** для начала. Там даже есть минимальный пример.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Но пока что вопрос открыт - вы можете подсказать, где ошибка в коде?

Comment: ToString преобразует класс в строку с названием класса, в редких случаях возвращает нужную информацию. Вам нужно возможно `Request.InputStream` читать тело, или другой метод использовать, но не ToString. В интернете много примеров как читать http, например вот https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx или вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273205/read-text-from-response

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Просто немного странно, так как парсинг я делал то же по примеру: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7r9K_WM4SY

Соответственно, использовал методы, идентичные тем, что на видео. И в итоге получаю совсем не тот результат.